# Как поменять настройки FancyBox? Ничего не помогает!

Tags: fancybox, javascript

Никак не могу изменить настройки фансибокс. Менял настройки в jquery.fancybox.js и в скрипте подключения на странице, но ничего не работает. Нужно включить полосу прокрутки и отключить автоматическое изменение картинки под размер окна браузера. Ничего не помогает.

Где и как правильно менять настройки? И почему может не работать смена настроек?

**ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕ**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();
        $(".fancybox-effects-a").fancybox({

            helpers: {
                title : {
                    type : 'outside'
                },
                overlay : {
                    speedOut : 0
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dasz5/2/).

Параметры [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/api).

Comment: А как эти настройки вставить? Например, на странице lpsystem.ru (там в коде скрипт подключения есть).

Comment: по вашей ссылке - третий блок <script>. А вообще, можно это описать в отдельном js-файле и подключить его к странице.

Comment: А почему не работают настройки в файле jquery.fancybox.js, которые я там прописываю?

Comment: Так это про полосы проктутки в самом окне? Я думал про полосу прокрутки браузера. Мне нужно, чтобы полоса у браузера не пропадала. Можно это сделать?

Comment: Обновил пример: http://jsfiddle.net/dasz5/3. Решается установкой свойства locked в false. (в блоке helpers -> overlay)

Comment: По вашей ссылке ошибка 404

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! Я не первый день ковырялся и понять не мог, как исправить.